# Do only believers hear the"shout" of the Lord?

Tags: 1-thessalonians, second-coming

Do only "caught up" (726) 1Th 4:16 believers (dead and alive) v17 hear (but not see) the "shout" (keleusma, 2752); "the voice (phone, 5456) of an archangel (arche, 746)"; "with the trumpet (salpigx, 4536) of God (Theos, 2316)? Ref: NKJV, Interlinear, The Complete Word Study Dictionary ISBN 0-89957-663-X

Answer (score 1):

There are two significant texts that bear upon this subject:

- 1 Thess 4:16 - For the Lord Himself will descend from heaven with a loud command, with the **voice of an archangel**, and with the trumpet of God, and the dead in Christ will be the first to rise. After that, we who are alive and remain will be caught up together with them in the clouds to meet the Lord in the air. And so we will always be with the Lord.

The resurrection of the dead is not confined to the righteous:

- John 5:28, 29 - Do not be amazed at this, for the hour is coming when **all who are in their graves will hear His voice** and come out—those who have done good to the resurrection of life, and those who have done evil to the resurrection of judgment.

Thus, it appears that **ALL** people will hear the voice of God calling them to life at one of the two great resurrections.  When these occur and whether they are at the same time is another matter entirely that might be the subject of another question.

Recall another verse:

- Rev 1:7 - Behold, He is coming with the clouds, and every eye will see Him—even those who pierced Him. And all the tribes of the earth will mourn because of Him. So shall it be! Amen.

Comment: Dottard - I agree with your assessment of John 5:28, 29 and I will ask a question "when these occur and whether they are at the same time". As to Rev 1:7, was trying to point to out that believers heard the Lord but "all" saw "the Son of Man" Matt 24:30:, Rev 1:7.

Comment: Dottard - However, I don't be think alive unbelievers hear the shout, voice or trumpet whether as "the Lord" !Th 4:15 "coming in the air" v17 or as "the Son of Man" coming to earth. Matt 24:30

Comment: @hank - I agree that is another question.